# How to display ":Invalid username and password" when I redirect to login page in Struts 1.3 application

Tags: java, jsp, struts-1

I'm trying to write an error message through an action class. The error message is `":Invalid username and password"` and should display when I redirect to login page.

1. I have created ApplicationResource.properties file.
2. I have written errors.add("invalid",new ActionMessage("invalid credentials"));

But the error message does not display.

---

UserRegAction.java

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.apache.struts.action.Action;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionErrors;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
//import com.opensymphony.xwork2.*;

import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForward;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionMapping;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionMessage;

import com.ex.form.*;
import com.ex.dao.*;


public class UserRegAction extends Action{

     public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws Exception {

         //---obj of form class--------------------------------
         ActionErrors errors = new ActionErrors();
         UserRegForm lf=(UserRegForm) form;

         String username = lf.getUname();
         String password = lf.getPassword();

         //---httpsession ob----------------------------------

         HttpSession session=request.getSession();
         session.setAttribute("uname", username);
         session.setAttribute("password", password);

         //---ob of dao class------------------------------------

         LogicDao dao= new LogicDao();

         if(dao.check(username,password))
         {
             System.out.println("GOT");
                return mapping.findForward("success");
                }
            else
                {
        errors.add("invalid",new ActionMessage("invalid credentials"));
         saveErrors(request,errors);
          return (mapping.findForward("failure"));


                }

     }


}
```

Comment: simplified layout of content

Answer (score 0):

For the failure case, in config XML, for the mentioned JSP file, use the html:errors tag to display all the errors. If you want to show only the specific error, use html:error tag with the message key to display only the specific error

Comment: Hi, Please will you share any example

Comment: Verify the site https://mkyong.com/struts/struts-validator-framework-example/